# How to minimize voltage-current phase shift in the output signal of a circuit?

Tags: amplifier, phase-shift

So, I have this circuit (Fig. 1, LTSpice ASC file here: https://github.com/PauloCarvalhoRJ/Circuits/blob/main/driver_speaker_5W_RMS.asc) designed for small scale geology investigations (using sound waves to quickly assess some rock properties such as porosity, permeability, fluid content, etc.).  The objective is to generate a sinusoidal output with a specific frequency (in this case, 18kHz).  A crystal-stabilized oscillator generates 0-5Vpp square pulses at the desired frequency.  R1, L1, L2 (I couldn't find a single 100mH coil in stores in my country) and C2 form a band-pass filter to round the signal, C1 couples the signal that is fed to the amplifier (most of the signal energy was filtered out) based on Q1.  A volume control is modeled with two resistors between the amplifier and an output stage designed around Q2.

[image]
**Figure 1:** The circuit with current lagging voltage across the speaker.

T1 is represented with two inductors coupled with a K1 SPICE directive and functions as an impedance matcher because driving the speaker directly results in too much back-EMF, severely distorting the output wave form.  D1 is there just in case as the simulation shows almost no back-EMF coming from the primary of T1.  The primary->secondary inductance ratio is 1:16, meaning a turn ratio of 1:4.  T1's coils will be wound around a toroidal ferrite core to maximize the coupling factor (set as 0.9 in the simulation).

The voice coil has a DC resistance of 6.3 ohms and an inductance of 160uH (measured with an LCR meter) and is the only part that cannot be changed (along with the supply voltages and input signal).  For those not acquainted with SPICE, the AKO (a kind of) directive allows you to change the parameters of an existing part so it matches those of what you have in hands (my LTSpice doesn't have TIP31C).

The simulated output signal (Fig. 2) is a really nice zero-centered almost-sinusoidal signal quite close to the design objective with the FFT showing the energy is concentrated around the target frequency.  The problem is the current across the speaker lagging behind the voltage, which impacts negativelly the power output.  I could simply oversize the power supply and output stage to get around 4-5W RMS in the speaker. However, the design is supposed to be part of an equipment to be used in the field, so it must be as most lightweight as possible. If the speaker polarity is wired in reverse, the current leads the voltage, so I believe there is a way to reduce the phase shift so I can get a good enough power factor.  However, I lack the EE wizardry to come up with a solution to that.  I'd appreciate any ideas, readings, etc.

[image]
**Figure 2:** the simulated output voltage (red curve) and current (green curve) across the speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The voice coil may have an inductance of 160µH at the frequency your LCR meter measured it at, but was that 18kHz? I'm thinking that its impedance will vary with frequency, and you'll need to measure it at exactly 18kHz, under the conditions where it is deployed, in order to determine what periphery is required to make the system purely resistive at that particular frequency. Is it even possible to do that electrically? Maybe you have to modify it physically to make it resonate at exactly 18kHz?

Comment: Surely the phase relationship between current through and voltage across the speaker will always be a function of the impedance of the speaker itself, which doesn't change regardless of how much stuff you connect around it. It might look resistive to the driver (T1.b), but all you've done is modified current in the *entire system* to be in phase with voltage across the *entire system*, not the voice coil itself. It seems to me that you need a different speaker, or to physically tune its resonant frequency.

Comment: @SimonFitch, as far as I know, the inductance value does not depend on frequency (unlike impedance).  18kHz is well within the design frquencies according to the manufacturer (5kHz - 30kHz).

Comment: @SimonFitch, yes, indeed.  I tried connecting many parts around the speaker, the phase shift remains the same.  The only way to match I and V is to reduce the inductance of the speaker to less than 25uH, that is, like you said, changing the speaker.

Comment: But that's exactly his point.  An LCR meter measures impedance and then uses the selected frequency to calculate the inductance.  That's why LCRs usually let you select between several different test frequencies.  If yours doesn't let you select one, then it probably uses a fixed value which is hopefully stated somewhere in the manual.

Comment: @SteKulov For the range selected (2mH) it uses 1kHz @ 150uA. "Smaller inductors (below 1 mH or so) should be measured at 1 kHz or higher, as they are often used in audio frequency or RF applications." source: https://bkprecision.my.site.com/desk/s/article/how-to-use-a-lcr-meter .  So, I don't believe the LCR meter is the root cause of the problem...  Anyway, voice coil geometry is r=23mm x l=2.2mm w/ 20 turns.  Using the relative permeabiliy of neodymium magnet (1.05), calculated inductance is 399uH, a value somewhat consistent with the LCR readout.